# Backup automatically

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api, backup

At our company we have a Google Spreadsheets which is shared by a link with different employees. This spreadsheet is saved on a Google Drive to which only I have access. The link is configured as such that anyone with the link can edit the spreadsheet since all employees need to be able to make changes to the file.

Although this is very useful, it also presents a risk in the form of data loss. If a user were to (accidentally) delete or alter the wrong data and saves the file, this data is permanently lost.

To prevent this I was wondering if it is possible to automatically have a backup created, say every day. Ideally, this backup is saved in the same Google Drive. I know I could install the desktop client and have the file backed up by our daily company backup, but it seems a bit ridiculous to install it for just one file. I'm sure there has to be another solution to this, ie with scripts.

Comment: Do you know revision history ? https://support.google.com/docs/answer/190843 Google create a new version you can restore at any time each time a user make a change in the file.

Comment: many other conceptual errors here. google drive desktop client will not backup a native google sheet and even if it did, it would be overwritten by the new bad edit. also no need to share to anyone with the link. instesd share with entire domain so you later see who made those changes in revision history. why a mirror is not a backup? http://slashdot.org/story/112253

Comment: @St3ph: I did not know that. Although not exactly what I was looking for, this is helpful enough for what we need. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @ZigMandel: I know the desktop client would simply overwrite existing files, I know how desktop syncing works. (I have been working with Dropbox and ownCloud in my private life for years.) 
About the sharing, it's not just people from the same domain that we share the file with since employees from other branches all over the world access the file. Thank you anyway. :)

Answer (score 1):

I followed the advice of St3ph and tried revision history. Not exactly what I meant, but an acceptable solution nonetheless.